# Swift 3 optional unwrapping

Tags: swift, swift3, option-type

I want to with a substring, that is delimited with another constant `String` "_TRALLALA"

This works fine like this:

```
 if let lb = s2.range(of: "_TRALLALA")?.lowerBound
 { let s3 = url.substring(to: lb)
 // do something  
 }
```

I would like to express this in a single if let like this:

```
 if let s3 =  url.substring(to: s2.range(of: "_TRALLALA")?.lowerBound)
 { // do something   
 }
```

But I get:

```
Value of optional type String.Index? not unwrapped
```

How is that expressed correctly

Comment: If you want to express it in a single `if`, wrap it to a function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native function that can do what you want, therefore you will have to wrap it into a function:

```
extension String {
    func substring(delimitedBy: String) -> String? {
        guard let range = self.range(of: delimitedBy) else {
            return nil
        }

        return self.substring(to: range.lowerBound)
    }
}

if let s3 = url.substring(delimitedBy: "_TRALLALA") {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`map` can be used with an *optional* to unwrap the value and use it, or to return `nil` if the optional is `nil`.  Using this, your statement can be written like this:

```
if let s3 = (s2.range(of: "_TRALLALA")?.lowerBound).map({ url.substring(to: $0) }) {
    // do something
}
```

or (slightly shorter) moving the `lowerBound` to after the `map`:

```
if let s3 = s2.range(of: "_TRALLALA").map({ url.substring(to: $0.lowerBound) }) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s2 = "Hello, playground"

var url = "some url"


let delimiter  =  "_TRALLALA"
let r  = s2.range(of: delimiter) ?? s2.startIndex..<s2.startIndex // if found nil then assigning empty Range

let s3  = url.substring(to: r.lowerBound)
if s3 != "" {
// do something
}
```

In Single line

```
let s3  = url.substring(to: (s2.range(of: "_TRALLALA") ?? s2.startIndex..<s2.startIndex).lowerBound)
if s3 != "" {
// do something

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let s3 = s2.range(of: "_TRALLALA").flatMap { url.substring(to: $0.lowerBound) }
{ 
    // do something   
}
```